# How to configure controlled inputs in React with Redux for state management?

Tags: reactjs, redux, state, textinput

I am trying to create a controlled input text field, value of which will eventually be used to make an API request. The problem is that on input (meaning key presses inside the text input) the query is set to 1 character at a time, and no text is showing up inside the actual input.

App component

```
import React from 'react';
import BookList from './BookList';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { setQuery } from '../actions';

const App = (props) => {
  return (
    <div>
      <input
        type="text"
        onChange={(e) => setQuery(e.target.value)}
        value={props.query}
      ></input>
      <BookList />
    </div>
  );
};

const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
  return {
    query: state.query,
  };
};

export default connect(mapStateToProps, { setQuery })(App);
```

Action

```
export const setQuery = (query) => {
  console.log(query);
  return {
    type: 'SET_QUERY',
    payload: query,
  };
};
```

Reducer

```
const queryReducer = (state = '', action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case 'SET_QUERY':
      return `${state}${action.payload}`;
    default:
      return state;
  }
};


export default combineReducers({
  query: queryReducer,
});
```

Comment: Since `e.target.value` is the value of the entire input, shouldn't the reducer case be `case 'SET_QUERY': return action.payload;`? Is something causing the `App` component to remount when you update the redux state?

Comment: I used useEffect to check for remounting, it doesn't. Also, thanks for drawing my attention to the payload.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `onChange` should be `onChange={(e) => props.setQuery(e.target.value)}` - so using the dispatch-bound version of `setQuery`.

Please be aware though that we do not recommend using `connect` with class components, but to use the `useSelector` and `useDispatch` hooks instead: https://redux.js.org/style-guide/style-guide/#use-the-react-redux-hooks-api

In general, this is a very old style of Redux you are writing here and you might have been following outdated tutorials. Modern Redux does not have switch..case reducers, ACTION_TYPES, hand-written action creators or the use of `connect`.

For an up-to-date tutorial, please follow the official tutorial:
https://redux.js.org/tutorials/essentials/part-1-overview-concepts